# Using .htaccess to hide files

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Let's say I have an `index.php` file inside my public directory.

Using `DirectoryIndex index.php`, I can set that file as my default index in my website.

But what if I don't want users to enter through `www.example.com/index.php`, **only by** `www.example.com`, how can I do that?

### EDIT

I added the following code:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php')) {
    readfile('404.html');
    exit;
}
```

at the beginning of `index.php`, so that entering by `www.example.com/index.php` would result in a 404 error but entering by `www.example.com` would not (thus, giving no information to a potential attacker of whether I use PHP or not). Not the best solution in the world but does work.

Answer (score 3):

Your question makes no sense. If you want to display a web page to the user who requests `www.example.com` then there has to be a [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) of some sort.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

will cause apache to search the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) of the server for index.php and then index.html and present the rendered version of the first one found to the user.

Comment: Yeah, I messed up, I meant `DirectoryIndex`, not "DefaultIndex". But how can I make users enter only through `www.example.com` and not `www.example.com/index.php` if that's even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really "hide" the page. You can deny access (Resulting in a 403 error) using htaccess. You can also redirect using mod_rewrite, either from /index.php (as suggested) to / or from /index.php to your 404 file (as you are doing now). The closest thing to hiding the page would be to use mod_rewrite to go from index.php to /, so when users enter either www.example.com or www.example.com/index.php, it shows up as www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

You could 'forbid' /index.php with something like

```
<Location /index.php>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</Location>
```

Or redirect from /index.php to / with mod_rewrite (which is a bit more user friendly).

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want to forbid it's access nor redirect the user, I wanted to hide it. I don't know if that's possible using .htaccess really

Answer (score 0):

I see in your comment to Koos that you want to hide index.php, which you can't really do. You best course of action is to place the parts you want hidden in another file and include that file in index.php. Done right the user will not see the include statement nor the included file, only the resulting output.